# Why i cant use getUserMedia() in express html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

When I run the html with the VScode live server, everything runs normally and the script inserted with   get the media normally, but when I start serving this html through an express server, the navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( ) doesn't work as it returns null//undefined, how to solve?

This is html code, runs normally with live reload and show the webcam:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>View Webcam</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style type="text/css">
      #container {
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 500px;
        height: 375px;
        border: 10px #333 solid;
      }

      #videoElement {
        width: 500px;
        height: 375px;
        background-color: #777;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="container">
      <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
      navigator.getUserMedia =
        navigator.getUserMedia ||
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.msGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.oGetUserMedia;

      console.log(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia)

      if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true }, handleVideo, videoError);
      }

      function handleVideo(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
      }

      function videoError(e) {}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[print from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyY47.png)

But, when i send this html with express, this happen(express code):

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve() + "/public/index.html")
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Running at port ${port}`)
})
```

[Print of error on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAjHd.png)

Any help?

Comment: can you include some code please? I don't understand your application without seeing some of it. specifically the `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(), etc. We need to see your express file.

Comment: sure, I edited the question including the code and screenshots from the google console